# How to return in mock the Task of T?

Tags: c#, mocking

I have a situation where I have to test a method which return a Task of T and I don't know how to setup the mock
here are an example:

```
    public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T:EntityBase
    { 
        Task<T> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues);
    }
```

The configuration of mock

```
  public class GenericConfiguration<T> where T : EntityBase
        {

            public Mock<IPersistenceService> MockPersistence { get; set; }
            public Mock<ILogService> MockLog { get; set; }
            public Mock<IReadOnlyRepository<T>> MockReadOnlyRepository { get; set; }
            public Mock<IRepository<T>> MockEntity { get; set; }
            public MockRepository MockRepository { get; set; }

            public void Setup()
            {
                MockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Loose) { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };
                MockPersistence = MockRepository.Create<IPersistenceService>();
                MockLog = MockRepository.Create<ILogService>();
                MockEntity = MockRepository.Create<IRepository<T>>();
                MockReadOnlyRepository = MockRepository.Create<IReadOnlyRepository<T>>();
            }
        /// <summary>
        /// Setup mock for FindAsync method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="results"> </param>
        public void SetupMockEntityRepositoryForFindAsync(List<T> results)
        {
            SetupMocForPersistence();
            MockEntity.Setup(r => r.FindAsync(It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(Task.FromResult<T>(null));
        }
}
```

Comment: You should tag this question with the language.

Comment: I don't see what is the problem. What you wanted to setup and what happens?

Comment: Your question is vague. Please make it clear to what exactly isn't working and if possible post a small yet complete reproduce of your problem.

Comment: Sorry was my mistake I was returning Task.FromResult<T>(null) instead of Task.FromResult<T>(results.FirstOrDefault())